# Complex differential equation for z

Tags: complex-numbers

I need help in solving the following differential equation for $z$, a complex number, and $a,A,B,C$ all real:
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=4ia(A\bar{z}+B\bar{z}^2+C\bar{z}^3)$$

I have tried the ansatz $z=ce^{mt}$ with $c,m$ complex but that gives $m=0$. Also trying $z=r(t)e^{i\theta}$ gave me equations I couldn't solve.

For $B=C=0$, the equation is:
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=4iaA\bar{z}$$
$$\implies mc=4iaA\bar{c}e^{(m-\bar{m})t}$$
This gives $\bar{m}=m$ and $m=4iaA\bar{c}/c$ If we take $c=re^{i\theta}$, $m=4iaAe^{-2i\theta}$. Since $m$ has to be real, $cos(2\theta)=0$ and thus the system can be solved exactly.

Comment: I think you should start with $B=C=0,$ write $z=x+iy$ with real smooth functions $x,y,$ and see what sort of ODE system you get, most likely rotation. Then allow nonzero $B$ in that setting; I think there should be some possible dynamical systems conclusions, but closed form seems optimistic.

Comment: Consider if on the left, you had $d\overline{z}/dt$ instead of $dz/dt$, you could just separate variables and integrate. But with conjugation, you lose the comfort of complex numbers and you'll have to split into components. Polar form looks more promising, but as @WillJagy says, start with the simple case to see what works.

Comment: The case $B=C=0$ is quite straightforward actually.  I have solved it, and either of the mentioned ansatzs work. However even with just B non zero, the trouble is the same.

Comment: @Mani , then edit that into the question.

Comment: @ManiJha  I did $B=C=0,$ then $A=a = 1/2,$ so $\dot{z}=i \bar{z}$ With $z(0) = 1,$ I get $z = \cosh t + i \sinh t,$ which works. With $z(0) = i,$ I get $z = \sinh t + i \cosh t.$

Comment: Try with B non-zero then. The equation I have given seems too much for even Mathematica :P